# How to bind a Button's IsEnabled member to a TextBox's content?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, c++-cx

I have a fairly standard setup: Based on whether the contents of a `TextBox` are empty, I want to enable/disable a `Button` control.

I tried, what would have worked in a WPF application, but that doesn't produce the desired behavior when running on the Windows Runtime:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox x:Name="ItemNameTextBox" Header="Item" />
    <Button Content="Add Item"
            IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=ItemNameTextBox,
                                Path=Text.Length,
                                Mode=OneWay}" />
</StackPanel>
```

At runtime, however, this produces the following debug output<sup>1)</sup>:

> ```
> Error: BindingExpression path error: 'Length' property not found on 'Windows.Foundation.IReference`1<String>'.
> ```

The error message is correct: `Windows::Foundation::IReference<String>` doesn't have a `Length` property.

**Question:** How do I bind the `IsEnabled` property of the `Button` to the `TextBox`s text length property? Do I have to implement a custom data converter, or can this be done using markup only?

---

<sup>1)</sup> *Full error output:*

> ```
> Error: BindingExpression path error: 'Length' property not found on 'Windows.Foundation.IReference`1<String>'. BindingExpression: Path='Text.Length' DataItem='Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TextBox'; target element is 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Button' (Name='null'); target property is 'IsEnabled' (type 'Boolean')
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't bind a boolean to an integer.

You need to create a converter that returns a boolean whose value is true or false depending on the value of the integer. In your case I assume that you want a length of zero to return false and a length of greater than zero to return true. If in c++/cx Length isn't a property but a method (unlike C#) then you're not going to be able to bind to it directly. You are going to have to bind the the Text property and then call the Length method in the converter:

```
public ref class LengthToIsEnabledConverter sealed : public Windows::UI::Xaml::Data::IValueConverter
{
public:
    virtual Platform::Object^ Convert( Platform::Object^ value,
                                       Windows::UI::Xaml::Interop::TypeName targetType,
                                       Platform::Object^ parameter,
                                       Platform::String^ language ) {
        Platform::String^ text = safe_cast<Platform::String^>( value );
        return ( text->Length() > 0 );
    }

    virtual Platform::Object^ ConvertBack( Platform::Object^ value,
                                           Windows::UI::Xaml::Interop::TypeName targetType,
                                           Platform::Object^ parameter,
                                           Platform::String^ language ) {
        throw ref new Platform::NotImplementedException();
    }
};
```

Then in your binding you add the converter and change the path to be just the Text:

```
IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=ItemNameTextBox,
                    Path=Text,
                    Mode=OneWay,
                    Converter={StaticResource LengthToIsEnabledConverter}" />
```

where the converter is declared in XAML like this:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <converters:LengthToIsEnabledConverter x:Key="LengthToIsEnabledConverter " />
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Comment: That didn't quite work out. As the debug diagnostic says: *"'Length' property not found"*, so that cannot be used. Passing the `Text` property instead, and evaluating the `Length()` method's return value in the converter works as expected. I'm not sure if all of that is necessary, though. Is `Platform::String` really this alien to databinding in the Windows Runtime?

Comment: @IInspectable - ah. Missed that aspect. I assumed that it was was the int -> bool failure that was causing that message rather than it not finding the property in the first place, but binding to the TextBox's Text is an acceptable solution.

Comment: This looks like C#. Is the `string` type a projection for `Platform::String`, and does it provide the `Length` as a property (as opposed to a member function)? I'm using C++/CX so I wouldn't know.

Comment: @IInspectable That'll teach me to read the tags properly ;) The answer should make sense now.